# Is there any point calling __sync_add_and_fetch to increment 0?

Tags: c

I have seen some code that calls `__sync_fetch_and_add(&value, 0)`, which seems to just read the `value`.

AFAIK, __sync_fetch_and_add() is to perform atomic add.

```
type __sync_fetch_and_add (type *ptr, type value, ...) 

__sync_fetch_and_add(value, 1);   // atomically increment value by 1
```

The type in question is a 32-bit int (x86 processor).

Is there any point calling it just to read? The way I see it, in a multi-thread / multi-core environment. Multiple threads could execute in any order. Even one thread reads the value in the middle of another __sync_fetch_and_add(), without lock, I see no harm.

Comment: One potential issue could be reading unaligned values where some bit-shifting is needed to read the full value, which some processors might not support atomically, but x86 seems to support `mov` atomically (for reading). However, the compiler might need the information that the read should be atomic, so it doesn't use cached values of the variable (i.e. it performs the read from the value).

Comment: It would help with context if you posted the surrounding code. Is the zero value hardwired? It is similar to atomic load but will do a read modify write cycle. It may need to do processor serialization.